# Implementing OAuth2 Facebook login without http.Redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, go

The following App Engine handler works to the extent that I can obtain a token:

```
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)

    oaConfig := map [string]string {
        "ClientID":     "(redacted)",
        "ClientSecret": "(redacted)",
        "Scope":        "email",
        "AuthURL":      "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize",
        "TokenURL":     "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token",
        "RedirectURL":  "http://www.example.com/",
    }

    code := r.FormValue("code")
    if code == "" {
        // 1. Code request
        url := oaConfig["AuthURL"] + 
            "?client_id=" + oaConfig["ClientID"] + 
            "&redirect_uri=" + oaConfig["RedirectURL"] + 
            "&state=SOME_UNIQUE_VALUE"
        http.Redirect(w, r, url, http.StatusFound)
    }

    // 2. Token request
    client := urlfetch.Client(c)
    tokenResponse, err := client.PostForm(oaConfig["TokenURL"],
        url.Values{
            "client_id": {oaConfig["ClientID"]},
            "redirect_uri": {oaConfig["RedirectURL"]},
            "client_secret": {oaConfig["ClientSecret"]},
            "code": {code},
        })

    if err != nil {
        // ...
    } else {
        // 3. Read token from response body
        defer tokenResponse.Body.Close()
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(tokenResponse.Body)
        if err != nil {
            // ...
        } else {
            token := string(body)
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

When hooked up to a template, this obtains a token response from Facebook and happily displays it. However, it would be nice not to have to redirect the user to example.com/?state=SOME_UNIQUE_VALUE&code=AQB0iYpAf8nMmX5blahblah#*=* in order to achieve a login.

Is there a way to use client.Get etc to visit the authorise URL, follow the redirect, obtain the code from the resulting query string and stuff it into a string for use by the handler? Without resorting to Ajax, that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to use client.Get etc to visit the authorise URL, follow the redirect, obtain the code from the resulting query string and stuff it into a string for use by the handler?

No, because the user may have to enter their login credentials to Facebook (and maybe connect to your app too, if they are a first time user) – and that can hardly be done, if you do it all from your server without showing it to the user.

If you want to recognize existing users re-visiting your app when they are already logged in to Facebook – that can only be done client-side. `FB.getLoginStatus` from the JS SDK is able to do that for you – it will recognize the user, and give you a valid access token for them at the same time.

Comment: OK, that was one of those brain-dead moments brought on by staring at the same problem for too long! Thanks :)